# Why is my mongo db not starting? (Bitnami MEAN Stack)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I installed the stack on my laptop and it was working fine. Then I restarted my computer and tried to start mongo and it would not start.

the error message I get in the manager is

> meanstack-3.0.6-1/mongodb/scripts/ctl.sh : mongodb could not be
>   started Stderr: child process exited abnormally

And when I try to start manually from a terminal I get an error saying data/db directory not found even though there is one.

I have already tried these steps with no luck:

> 1) Remove .lock file
>
> sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
>
> 2) repair the mongodb
>
> mongod –repair
>
> 3) start the mongodb
>
> sudo service mongodb start
>
> 4) start the mongo client

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @JonathanS. linux ubuntu

Comment: Did you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here. Can you check the error log at installdir/mongodb/log/mongodb.log to provide us more information about your issue? Please note that the Bitnami installers are completely self-contained and run independently of the rest of the software or libraries installed on your system so you don't need to remove /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock. To start MongoDB of Bitnami you have to use the ctlscript.sh that we provide in the installer `installdir/ctlscript.sh start`. You will find more information about it using this link: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/mongoDB

Comment: @JotaMartos every time I restart computer mongo will not start. apache starts but not mongo

Answer (score 2):

just a tip: check your **available free disc space**, sometimes this kind of problems occurs because **mongDb** don't have enough space on the disc to run the server.
 if this is not working then manually check the log file **Mongodb.log** at '**yourPath\bitnami\meanstack-3.x.x-x\mongodb\log**' hear you will sure find some proper clue.

Answer (score 1):

Rename below file to anything

meanstack-3.0.6-1/mongodb/data/db/mongod.lock

restart mongodb from bitnami

note:-- mongodb installed in your system is different then installed through bitnami, they are using different ports, i.e. currently you have two instance of mongodb installed in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install an old version of Mongo so I replaced all the files in the /bin folder with the old version and then I was getting the error "mongodb could not be started".  I then deleted all the files under data/db and restarted using "./ctlscript.sh start mongodb" which worked.